# Parsing an array in swift with null values (not nil)

Tags: ios

I'm calling webservice in swift for an iOS app, i have the webservice returns data in the form of array .. like this :

```
["354", "Air Conditioning", "null", "2", "Street EG", null, null, null, null, null, "50", "20", "2017-01-22T14:30:46Z", "27", "24", "18", "13", "0", null, null, null, null ] ..
```

the problem is that when it populates an array it suppresses the null values and reduces the length of the array which is not right, i need the data to be "null" if it is null or nil because i get values by index and each index is know to be null or with value but it must be there

Comment: Please post code showing what you have already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use optionals. Your array would be

```
var array = [String?]
```

With optionals, you can accept **nil** values.

When you append the value to the array, now it can accept **nil**

Comment: Perfect Answer for checking [null] from API response.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert this JSON with something like `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)`, the resulting array doesn't suppress the `null` entries. They're represented by `NSNull` objects. If your `null` entries are suppressed, then you should edit your question to share the code that is doing that. Standard JSON parsing routines will preserve these values without incident. For example, in Swift:

```
guard let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data), let array = jsonObject as? [Any] else {
    print("can't parse it")
    return
}

for object in array {
    if object is NSNull {
        print("Hey, it's null!")
    } else {
        print("It's not null, it's \(object)")
    }
}
```

You can see that the `null` values are preserved, represented with `NSNull` (except the first one, which because it's in quotes, is a string with four characters, `"null"`).

Comment: Tanks for the info